# How to receive tcp connection data in Node js Continously

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

My previous Project is developed with jsxmlsocket(https://www.developerfusion.com/project/18979/jsxmlsocket). It is working with flash. Js xml socket connected with ip and port then The response like this {"ClientID":"202.75.xx.xxx:xxxxx","ServerDist":"1"} By using this client id i am sending vehicle device id, So i am getting all the vehicle information continously.

```
xmls.onData = function(data1) {
        console.log('getData: ' + data1)
        console.log(data1)
        var strs = (data1.slice(0, -1));
        data = JSON.parse(strs)
        if (data.ServerDist == 1) {
            var sentMsg = '{\"ClientID\":\"' + data.ClientID + '\",\"TrackSystemNos\":\"1399288XXXX|\"}';
            console.log('Sent Msg: ' + sentMsg)
            xmls.send(sentMsg);
        } else {
            console.log('New Positions')
        });
```

But now i am working in NODEJS i am getting Client id and ServerDist, After sednig ClientID with device id i am not getting correct client information. It is not calling client.on(). So can you please help me how to get the device data

```
client.on('data', function(data1) {
console.log('getData: ' + data1)
var strs = (data1.slice(0, -2));
data = JSON.parse(strs)
const newLocal = 'New Positions';
if (data.ServerDist == 1) {
    var sentMsg = '{\"ClientID\":\"' + data.ClientID + '\",\"TrackSystemNos\":\"1399288XXXX|\"}';
    console.log('Sent Msg: ' + sentMsg)
    client.emit(sentMsg);
    client.write(sentMsg);
} else
    console.log(newLocal);
```

});

First time client id is getting, But Second time data1 is not getting any information

I Need Response Like this

```
{ "SimID":"139928XXXXX",   "SignalType":"Locate",   "DateTime":"2019-10-24 13:31:40",   "Longitude1":"0.00000",   "Latitude1":"0.00000",   "Longitude":"0.00000",   "Latitude":"0.00000",   "Velocity":"0",   "Angle":"0",   "LocateStatus":"NoLocate",   "StatusA":"OFF",   "StatusB":"OFF",   "StatusC":"OFF",   "StatusD":"OFF",   "TurnStatus":"0",   "AccStatus":"OFF",   "Temperature":"0",   "Temperature2":"",   "Temperature3":"",Temperature4":"",   "Oil":"0",   "Oil2":"0",   "LevelNum":"12.13",   "OilIn":"0",   "OilOut":"0",   "Miles":"7611669",   "ParkingSpan":"1.11:54:59",   "TodayMile":"61321"}
```

Answer (score 0):

So for continuous data (in this case at 1Hz).  I setup the server.js as

```
const net = require('net');

var init = {
    ClientID: null,
    ServerDist: 1,
};

var dummy = {
    SimID: '139928XXXXX',
    SignalType: 'Locate',
    DateTime: '2019-10-24 13:31:40',
    ...
};


function send_data(socket) {
    let temp = JSON.stringify(dummy) + '# ';
    socket.write(temp);
}

const server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.on('data', data => {
        # init is a raw string buffer so I had to .toString it
        if (data.toString() === 'init') {
            init.ClientID = socket.remoteAddress + ':' + socket.remotePort;
            let temp = JSON.stringify(init) + '# ';
            socket.write(temp);
        }
        else {
            # Call send_data every 1000 ms with socket as an arg.
            setInterval(send_data, 1000, socket )

        }
    });
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Then the client becomes easier frankly

```
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function () {
    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
    client.write('init');
    console.log('Sent: ', 'init');
});

var ClientID = '';

client.on('data', function (data) {
        let strs = (data.slice(0, -2));
        let Cdata = JSON.parse(strs);
        console.log('Response:' + JSON.stringify(Cdata));
        if (Cdata.ServerDist === 1) {
            ClientID = Cdata.ClientID;
            let sentMsg = {ClientID: ClientID, TrackSystemNos: '13992881XXX|'};
            client.write(JSON.stringify(sentMsg));
            console.log('Sent: ' + JSON.stringify(sentMsg));
        }
    }
);
```

I get back

```
CONNECTED TO: 127.0.0.1:1337
Sent:  init
Response:{"ClientID":"127.0.0.1:35554","ServerDist":1}
Sent: {"ClientID":"127.0.0.1:35554","TrackSystemNos":"13992881XXX|"}
Response:{"SimID":"139928XXXXX","SignalType":"Locate","DateTime":"2019-10-24 13:31:40","Longitude1":0,"Latitude1":0,"Longitude":0,"Latitude":0,"Velocity":0,"Angle":0,"LocateStatus":"NoLocate","StatusA":"OFF","StatusB":"OFF","StatusC":"OFF","StatusD":"OFF","TurnStatus":0,"AccStatus":"OFF","Temperature":0,"Temperature2":null,"Temperature3":null,"Temperature4":null,"Oil":0,"Oil2":0,"LevelNum":12.13,"OilIn":0,"OilOut":0,"Miles":7611669,"ParkingSpan":"1.11:54:59","TodayMile":"61321"}
Response:{"SimID":"139928XXXXX","SignalType":"Locate","DateTime":"2019-10-24 13:31:40","Longitude1":0,"Latitude1":0,"Longitude":0,"Latitude":0,"Velocity":0,"Angle":0,"LocateStatus":"NoLocate","StatusA":"OFF","StatusB":"OFF","StatusC":"OFF","StatusD":"OFF","TurnStatus":0,"AccStatus":"OFF","Temperature":0,"Temperature2":null,"Temperature3":null,"Temperature4":null,"Oil":0,"Oil2":0,"LevelNum":12.13,"OilIn":0,"OilOut":0,"Miles":7611669,"ParkingSpan":"1.11:54:59","TodayMile":"61321"}
Response:{"SimID":"139928XXXXX","SignalType":"Locate","DateTime":"2019-10-24 13:31:40","Longitude1":0,"Latitude1":0,"Longitude":0,"Latitude":0,"Velocity":0,"Angle":0,"LocateStatus":"NoLocate","StatusA":"OFF","StatusB":"OFF","StatusC":"OFF","StatusD":"OFF","TurnStatus":0,"AccStatus":"OFF","Temperature":0,"Temperature2":null,"Temperature3":null,"Temperature4":null,"Oil":0,"Oil2":0,"LevelNum":12.13,"OilIn":0,"OilOut":0,"Miles":7611669,"ParkingSpan":"1.11:54:59","TodayMile":"61321"}
```

Comment: What does the emit do in this context?

Comment: Thanks!. I need exactly like this but small difference. Are you using server.js? 
My issues is server is in .Net(I dont no what wrote in that). But when i run the jsxmlsocket(https://www.developerfusion.com/project/18979/jsxmlsocket) with flash it is continously giving data. In future flash is not working so i moved to node js This is for live vehicle monitoring system purpose. After sending Client ID + Sim id it is giving realtime data. Still i am unable to get the realtime data

Comment: Okay I thought that might be it so I did that too.  Hold on I will update it.

Comment: can i have private chate with you? i struggled from last 1 Month with this issue

Comment: I can edit the client program only. I cant write server program. the server is already giving a response from .Net  It is already working jsxmlsocket. So i need to change client only in nodejs

Comment: Sorry i did'nt receive any mail showmacktest@gmail.com, My Server is in .Net DLL file. So I can't change the server. So only write Client Program. instead of jsxmlsocket(Instead of (developerfusion.com/project/18979/jsxmlsocket it is .html with flash + JS) It is working. Now i need nodejs or pure javascript

Comment: var s = new jsXMLSocket();
    s.onReady = function() {
        s.connect('202.71.103.XXX', '2000');
    }
    s.onConnect = function(success, error) {  console.log('Connected')
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        s.setup('#socket');
    });
    s.onData = function(data1) {
        console.log('getData: ' + data1);
        var strs = (data1.slice(0, -1));
        data = JSON.parse(strs);
        if (data.ServerDist == 1) {
            var sentMsg = '{"ClientID":"' + data.ClientID + '","TrackSystemNos":"13992881XXX|"}';
            s.send(sentMsg);
        }
    }

Comment: The above code is working with flash (jsXMLSocket.swf). Without any server changes. So I need replacement of the above code.  The reason is flash will not work in future.
Thank you