# Node Js TCP Client not receiving data in a loop

Tags: sockets, tcp

I need continuous data receiving. but i tried with out setinterval() but no success. Then i tried setinterval() also no success i am receiving first response after sending message no success can you please help me.
this is the output;[enter image description here][1]

```
var HOST = '202.71.103.XXX';
var PORT = XXXX;
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
    client.write('init');
    setInterval(getData, 1000);
});

function getData() {
    console.log('fun called')
    client.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Get Data: ' + data)
        Cdata = JSON.parse(data.slice(0, -2))
        if (Cdata.ServerDist == 1) {
            var sentMsg = '{"ClientID":"' + Cdata.ClientID + '","TrackSystemNos":"13992881XXX|"}';  
            client.write(sentMsg)
            console.log('Sent Msg: ' + sentMsg)
        }
    });
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mt0Y.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I am not 100% sure what your specific issue is but I wrote a simple client and server based on your code and it works pretty well so see if that helps you.

Server:

```
const net = require('net');

var dummy = {
    ServerDist: 1
};

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    let temp = JSON.stringify(dummy)
    console.log(temp);
    socket.write(temp);
    socket.on('data', data => {
        let temp = JSON.stringify(dummy);
        console.log(temp);
        socket.write(temp);
    });
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Client

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 1337;
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function () {
    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
    client.write('init');
});

client.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('Get Data: ' + data);
        let Cdata = JSON.parse(data);
        if (Cdata.ServerDist === 1) {
            let sentMsg = {ClientID: 'Bob', TrackSystemNos: '13992881XXX'};
            client.write(JSON.stringify(sentMsg));
            console.log('Sent Msg: ' + JSON.stringify(sentMsg))
        }
    }
);
```

Output:

```
Get Data: {"ServerDist":1}
Sent Msg: {"ClientID":"Bob","TrackSystemNos":"13992881XXX"}
Get Data: {"ServerDist":1}
Sent Msg: {"ClientID":"Bob","TrackSystemNos":"13992881XXX"}
Get Data: {"ServerDist":1}
Sent Msg: {"ClientID":"Bob","TrackSystemNos":"13992881XXX"}
Get Data: {"ServerDist":1}
Sent Msg: {"ClientID":"Bob","TrackSystemNos":"13992881XXX"}
Get Data: {"ServerDist":1}
Sent Msg: {"ClientID":"Bob","TrackSystemNos":"13992881XXX"}
Get Data: {"ServerDist":1}
Sent Msg: {"ClientID":"Bob","TrackSystemNos":"13992881XXX"}
Get Data: {"ServerDist":1}
Sent Msg: {"ClientID":"Bob","TrackSystemNos":"13992881XXX"}
```

*Old Answer*
I believe your problem is setinterval is a asynchronous call. So as soon as you call it the code continues out of the connect function (most likely ending the connection).  The setinterval gets the first response because it is there from the call before the close but since the connection is closed it doesn't get any more.

Have you tried using a while loop inside the connect to keep the connection open?

Comment: Also you can add a `client.on('end', () => {
  console.log('disconnected from server');
});`  to see if it is closing.

Comment: connection is not closed. and client.on('data', function(data) {}); data is continously getting data? This is my output; https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mt0Y.png

Comment: From the output img, the interval keeps running but it doesn't show the client.on('data') event firing.  Also I am not sure you need to register the event handler for on data over and over again.

Comment: Thankyou Dr Code, I need exactly this functionality. But in my server is in .Net. 
Can you pleae check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58606828/how-to-receive-tcp-connection-data-in-node-js-continously

Comment: One thing I am confused on what is this for? `Cdata = JSON.parse(data.slice(0, -2))`   It is in the linked version as well.  Can you print out the raw data you get from the server for me?  I know what it does it chops off the last two characters on the json string.  Is there something there?Nevermind I see it its the # character.

Comment: I attempted to put an answer on the link.  If you want to move over there.

Comment: When i used slice(0, -2) Then it is json string format other wise # and some other character is added from server side